# Ovewrite a data extension field in the send log

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, dataextensions, field-update

I am trying to overwrite the data that comes into the send-log from a Data Extension field on an email send.

I've researched UpdateDE but I'm not trying to permanently alter the data extension. I'm trying to null the value for all recipients/users in the DE on a particular send and save a code snippet for when it is needed.

The DE field is `Id`, so I've tried:

```
%%[
var @Id
set @Id = ""
]%%

<p>
ID: %%Id%%
</p>
```

In this test, it still outputs the original DE Id.

Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Ran into this years ago. When DE column and a variable of the same name is passing a value, the value in the DE will always win (win = writing to the send log). That's just the way it was, and I guess still is. We ultimately resorted to creating a new column in the send log - not always possible, and not ideal - but it was what had to be done to move forward.

Answer (score 0):

The reason it returns the system-generated ID is that you still reference it with the logic you have written. You need to reference the ampscript variable, @Id that you just created. It's done like this:

```
%%[
var @Id
set @Id = ""
]%%

<p>
ID: %%=v(@Id)=%%
</p>
```

This should work

Comment: Thank you for the answer.  Do you think that new blank ID would show up in the send log or would it still pull in the original DE field?

Comment: It would still get the DE field. Changing data in data views is a bit complicated